# Session object not returning the variable back

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello I am new to facebook app development and working over my first app.
The flow of my app is like that that first page is the landing page that checks whether user has like the page or not, if the user has already liked the page it then redirects the user to the next page.

As the $signed_request object is retrieved in the first landing page but will be used throughout the app, so I want to pass this variable to next page through $_SESSION[] object but am unable to retrieve it on the other page.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    …
</head>
<body>
<?php
            $app_id = "160336875618730";
            $app_secret = "b14ac6d2b7frewdb259599b06983e881";
            $canvas_page = "http://apps.facebook.com/myapp";
            $auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . $canvas_page . "&scope=email,read_stream,publish_stream,user_photos";

            $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
            list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
            $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
            $_SESSION['signed_request']=$data;

… …..
```

And on page2.php while am trying to retrieve it like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD H   ...
... ... 
<body>
<?php
$data = $_SESSION['signed_request'];

            //User Info. Variables:
            try {
                $userId = $data["user_id"];
                echo "ID:".$userId;
                $userName =json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/' . $userId)) -> name;
…
```

It’s not giving me the variable’s back.

kindly help me with this.

Comment: On the first page print out `$data` and `$_SESSION` to check you have the data and it's gone into the session. Print out the `$_SESSION` on page2 to see if it has any content at all using `print_r()`. Also check you are viewing both pages either both on www or both not on www. If you're interchanging like that the session data won't be available on both.

Comment: Forgot to mention, also check your PHP/Apache error log for any clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing a redirect you need to call session_write_close() before performing the redirect. This forces PHP to write the session data.